# Spacing of item list in tikz node + node wording position

Tags: spacing, itemize, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

**Yes, there are in fact 2 questions but I hope they are close enough to be related.**

Hi all, I'm trying to draw a flow chart using tikz. When I want to put a itemize list in the node `solb` I couldn't make the spacing of the list to be `single` and left aligned as I wish.

Also when I add the description to the arrow I don't know how to fix the description north *and* center to the horizontal part of the arrow.

It'd be the best if someone can help me together on these 2 things. Thanks a lot.

My MWE is here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{rec} = [
    rectangle,
        minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm,
    text centered,
    draw = black, fill = white]
\tikzstyle{recw80} = [
    rectangle]
\tikzstyle{recw30} = [
    rectangle,
        minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm,
    text width = 3cm,
    draw = black, fill = white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [rec] {Hi};
\node (q1) [recw80, below of=start, yshift=-0.5cm] {};
\node (solb) [recw30, right of=q1, xshift=6.5cm] {
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\begin{itemize}
        \item Point 1,
        \item Point 2, or
        \item Point 3.
    \end{itemize}\end{varwidth}};

\draw [arrow] (solb) |- node[anchor=south] {How are you?} (start);

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. (I also do not understand the purpose of the `\makebox`.)You can use the `enumitem` package to customize you `itemize` environment, use `align=left`, and use `pos=0.75` to have the edge label in the middle of the horizontal stretch. I also recommend using the `positioning` library, i.e. instead of `below of`, say, use `below=<distance> of`. In your example this allows us to eliminate the auxiliary `q1` node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{rec/.style={
    rectangle,
        minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm,
    text centered,
    draw = black, fill = white},
recw80/.style={
    rectangle},
recw30/.style={
    rectangle,
        minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm,
    text width = 3cm,align=left,
    draw = black, fill = white},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [rec] {Hi};
\node (solb) [recw30,below right=0.5cm and 6.5cm of start] {
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]
        \item Point 1,
        \item Point 2, or
        \item Point 3.
    \end{itemize}\end{varwidth}};

\draw [arrow] (solb) |- node[pos=0.75,above] {How are you?} (start);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A Ti\emph{k}Z picture.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ```makebox``` to make the whole flow chart align at center (but I forgot which question in this site gave me this idea).

Comment: @Yuki.F OK,I see. If you put the picture in a figure, you can achieve this with `\centering`.

Comment: ```\centering``` where? Just after ```\begin{figure}```?

Comment: @Yuki.F Yes, that's right.

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: @Yuki.F I added an explicit example. It works on my TeX installation and is a rather standard thingy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102452/discussion-between-yuki-f-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: Looks like because I did not mention the requirement that recw80 is (a lot) wider than rec that if I add this requirement back, the ```centering``` doesn't work anymore. Latecomers can stick to the ```makebox``` line to force the diagram be center aligned as a whole in case the box widths are quite different to each other.

Comment: @Yuki.F Yes. I made the example here more minimal by eliminating `q0` and more versatile by loading and using `positioning`.